# Should I always complete vert.x promise?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, vert.x

I need to implement batch job to migrate datafrom one mongodb collection to another.

I want to make it in async way. Please look at the following example

```
private void runBatch() {
   mongo.count("clients", new JsonObject(), countResult -> {
      if (countResult.succeeded()) {
         int count = countResult.result().intValue();
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i+=200) {
            final int skip = i;
            final int limit = skip + 199;
            // create new promise to process every 200 clints
            vertx.executeBlocking(promise -> {
               FindOptions options = new FindOptions();
              options.setSkip(skip);
              options.setLimit(limit);
              options.setSort(new JsonObject().put("_id", 1));
              mongo.findWithOptions("clients", query, options, findResult -> {
                  List<JsonObject> clients = findResult.result();
                  for (JsonObject client : clients) {
                     mongo.save("best_clients", client, saveResul -> {
                        // TODO add logging
                     });
                  }
              });
            }, result -> {
               // TODO add logging
            });
         }
      }
   });
}
```

Inside `executeBlocking` I'm running a lot of async methods

I'm really confise Should I run somewhere `promise.complete()`?

Maybe My approach is incorrect and I shouldn't work inside promise with 200 object either pass one object for one promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A promise is usually used to represent the eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation; then, based on the promise's successful completion or failure, some operation is being carried out. (logging, acknowledging that some operation was carried out etc)

It beats the purpose of using a promise if it's not completed or its value never used.

Also remember that the value of a promise, if not completed, could be set (possibly by another thread depending on code implementation) which could lead to unexpected behavior. So it's recommended to always complete promises.